# R split column by fixed width

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the date and time are mixed like this:

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4)
DDMMYY <-c(100310,110310,120310,130310)
HHMM <- c(2205,1045,1110,2250)
df <- data.frame(ID,DDMMYY,HHMM)
df

ID  DDMMYY  HHMM
1   100310  2205
2   110310  1045
3   120310  1110
4   130310  2250
```

I want to split the date and time so that DD, MM, YY, HH and MM fall into separate columns like this:

```
ID  DD  MM  YY  HH  MM
1   10  3   10  22  5
2   11  3   10  10  45
3   12  3   10  11  10
4   13  3   10  22  50
```

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to use `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
extract(extract(df, DDMMYY, c("DD","MM", "YY"), "(..)(..)(..)",
          convert=TRUE), HHMM, c("HH", "MM"), "(..)(..)", convert=TRUE)
#  ID DD MM YY HH MM
#1  1 10  3 10 22  5
#2  2 11  3 10 10 45
#3  3 12  3 10 11 10
#4  4 13  3 10 22 50
```

Or you could use `strsplit` from `base R`

```
 df[,c("DD", "MM", "YY", "HH", "MM")] <- do.call(data.frame,lapply(df[,-1],
       function(x) do.call(rbind,lapply(strsplit(as.character(x),
                     '(?<=..)(?=..)', perl=TRUE), as.numeric))))

 df[,-(2:3)]
 #  ID DD MM YY HH MM.1
 #1  1 10  3 10 22    5
 #2  2 11  3 10 10   45
 #3  3 12  3 10 11   10
 #4  4 13  3 10 22   50
```

Comment: I haven't used `extract` before. I gotta check it out. Thanks for this example. +1

Answer (score 4):

For fun, here are three more alternatives:

#### Convert your data to actual dates and use `format`

```
within(df, {
  var <- paste(DDMMYY, HHMM)
  var <- strptime(var, format = "%d%m%y %H%M")
  mm <- format(var, "%M")
  hh <- format(var, "%H")
  YY <- format(var, "%y")
  MM <- format(var, "%m")
  DD <- format(var, "%d")
  rm(var, DDMMYY, HHMM)
})
#   ID DD MM YY hh mm
# 1  1 10 03 10 22 05
# 2  2 11 03 10 10 45
# 3  3 12 03 10 11 10
# 4  4 13 03 10 22 50
```

#### Use `read.fwf` (and a bunch of other nested stuff)

```
cbind(df[1], 
      setNames(do.call(
        cbind, lapply(df[-1], function(x) {
          read.fwf(textConnection(as.character(x)), 
                   widths = rep(2, nchar(x[1])/2))
          })), 
        c("DD", "MM", "YY", "hh", "mm")))
#   ID DD MM YY hh mm
# 1  1 10  3 10 22  5
# 2  2 11  3 10 10 45
# 3  3 12  3 10 11 10
# 4  4 13  3 10 22 50
```

#### Use `separate` from "tidyr"

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  separate(DDMMYY, into = c("DD", "MM", "YY"), sep = c(2, 4)) %>% 
  separate(HHMM, into = c("hh", "mm"), sep = 2)
#   ID DD MM YY hh mm
# 1  1 10 03 10 22 05
# 2  2 11 03 10 10 45
# 3  3 12 03 10 11 10
# 4  4 13 03 10 22 50
```