# break the line if it exceeds certain length

Tags: html, r

Is there a way to break the vector and put in next line if it is long texts

```
> asd <- c('ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffsdaa')
> HTML(asd)
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffsdaa
```

Expected output

```
fffffffffffffffffff
fffffffffffffffsdaa
```

Comment: If you need next line, perhaps `gsub("(.{25})", "\\1\n", asd)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R split column by fixed width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660571/r-split-column-by-fixed-width)